# HQL editor in Intellij Idea

Tags: spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, hql

I've got the Ultimate Edition of Intellij IDEA v. 13.1.5 and a Spring Web project. I cannot manage to get the HQL console working. I've added the database datasource through `View | Tool Windows | Database`. Then I add JPA module to my project and then I'm stuck. I set Hibernate as default JPA provider, there are two descriptors `persistence.xml` and `orm.xml` to be added. However I'm using `spring-cfg.xml`, I tried adding `spring-cfg.xml` as the persistence descriptor but no dice. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project settings dialog, you need to add a JPA Configuration Descriptor (use the + at the bottom). If you're using Maven, it should find the auto-generated one. (You may need to do a maven compile first.)